# write records just in time when the value (for id of something) is changing

Tags: f#

How to write records just in time when the value for id of something is changing ? id for each record when ture->false and false->true for some list?

for example table

```
id value
 1 0
 2 0
 2 0
 2 0
 1 0
 2 1 --> the only changes here
 2 1
 1 0
 2 0 --> and here (node with id 2 changed 1 -> 0 )
 1 1 --> node with id 1 changed 0 -> 1
```

result table

```
2 1
2 0
1 1
```

my idea is not functional and a bit weird, I'm thinking about functional or linq way of making the same.

```
                        let oop = ref (filteredsq
                                       |> Seq.distinctBy(fun (node,v,k) -> k) 
                                       |> Seq.map(fun (node,v,k) -> k, false )
                                       |> Array.ofSeq )
                        [for (node,value,key) in filteredsq do
                            let i = ref 0
                            for (k,v) in !oop do
                                if key = k && value <> v then
                                    (!oop).[!i] <- (k,value)
                                    yield node
                            i := !i + 1 ]
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you give an example `filteredsq`?

Comment: @Daniel not sure about why I must to get IndexOutOfRangeException, I'll check it deeper tomorrow. filteredsq got hard structure. node is some type, list of which I need to get in final. v is value - bool and k is key - integer.

Comment: I removed that comment shortly after I posted it. I was mistaken. I posted an answer, which I think you can use as a drop-in replacement for your current function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I fully understand your question, but the following gives the right output according to your sample. The idea is to first filter out values that don't have the right key and then use `Seq.pairwaise` (as in jpalmer's solution) to find the places where the value changes:

```
let input = [ (1, 0); (2, 0); (2, 0); (2, 0); (1, 0); (2, 1); (2, 1); (1, 0); (2, 0) ]

let findValueChanges key input =
  input 
  |> Seq.filter (fun (k, v) -> k = key) // Get values with the right key
  |> Seq.pairwise                       // Make tuples with previous & next value
  |> Seq.filter (fun ((_, prev), (_, next)) -> prev <> next) // Find changing points
  |> Seq.map snd                        // Return the new key-value pair (after change)
```

If you wanted to find changes for all different keys, then you could use `Seq.groupBy` to find all possible keys (then you wouldn't need the first line in `findValueChanges`):

```
input 
|> Seq.groupBy fst
|> Seq.map (fun (k, vals) -> findValueChanges k vals)
```

(For your input, there are no changes in values for the key 1, because the value is always `1, 0`)

Comment: thank you for review. Your code is to related to example :) just read my code in the question to get idea. I need to handle all changes (with any if (not only 2)).

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite follow your code sample. Can you extend your example to demonstrate the cases that my answer doesn't handle correctly ?

Comment: It's fine now (except that I lost my order but it's not really big trouble) Thank you. [ Opened pairwise for myself :) ]

Comment: @nCdy - if the `groupBy` changes order then you can just pass the original `input` to `findValueChanges` in the lambda function in the second example and it will work using the original order.

Answer (score 3):

I think if you define a function like the following:

```
let getChanges f items =
  items
  |> Seq.map (fun x -> f x, x)
  |> Seq.pairwise
  |> Seq.choose (fun ((a, _), (b, x)) -> if a <> b then Some x else None)
```

Then you can do:

```
filteredsq
|> Seq.groupBy (fun (_, _, k) -> k)
|> Seq.collect (fun (_, items) ->
  items 
  |> getChanges (fun (_, value, _) -> value)
  |> Seq.map (fun (node, _, _) -> node))
|> Seq.toList
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like

```
List
|> List.toSeq
|> Seq.pairwise
|> Seq.pick (fun ((fa,fb),(sa,sb)) -> if fb <> sb then Some(sa,sb) else None)
```

Comment: Thank you but I need to compare values with same id only. check example tables.  2 1;  1 0;  2 0 - here I don't register 2.1 -> 1.0, I register 2.1 -> 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated**

```
open System.Collections.Generic

let filter (acc:'a) (f:('a -> 'b -> bool * 'a)) (s:'b seq) = 
    let rec iter (acc:'a) (e:IEnumerator<'b>) = 
        match e.MoveNext() with
        | false -> Seq.empty 
        | true -> match f acc e.Current with
                  | (true,newAcc) -> seq { yield e.Current; yield! iter newAcc e}
                  | (false,newAcc) -> seq { yield! iter newAcc e}
    iter acc (s.GetEnumerator())

let skipUntilChange (f : 'a -> 'b) (s : 'a seq) = 
    s |> Seq.skip 1
    |> filter (s |> Seq.head |> f)
        (fun a b -> if a = f b then false,f b else true,f b)

[(1,0);(2,0);(2,0);(2,0);(1,0);(2,1);(2,1);(1,0);(2,0);]
|> Seq.mapi (fun c (i,v) -> (i,v,c))
|> Seq.groupBy (fun (i,v,c) -> i)
|> Seq.map (snd >> skipUntilChange (fun (_,v,_) -> v))
|> Seq.concat |> Seq.sortBy (fun (i,v,c) -> c)
|> Seq.map (fun (i,v,c) -> (i,v))
|> printfn "%A"
```

Comment: Thank you. I need some time to understand it :) after all, there are some errors : Error 3 The non-generic type 'System.Collections.IEnumerator' does not expect any type arguments, but here is given 1 type argument(s)

Comment: @nCdy : You need to `open System.Collections.Generic`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just use an internal mutable dictionary to keep track of the last-seen values for each key and yield (key,value) when any value is different from the last value at that key:

```
let filterChanges (s:('a*'b) seq) =   
    let dict = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<'a,'b>()
    seq {
        for (key,value) in s do
            match dict.TryGetValue(key) with
            | false,_ -> dict.[key] <- value
            | true,lastValue -> 
                if lastValue <> value then
                    yield (key,value)
                    dict.[key] <- value
    }
```

Test:

```
> filterChanges [(1,0);(2,0);(2,0);(2,0);(1,0);(2,1);(2,1);(1,0);(2,0);(1,1)];;
val it : seq<int * int> = seq [(2, 1); (2, 0); (1, 1)]
```